# How to get a processed dataset, if the processing steps are not tensor operations?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I have an instance of `tf.data.Dataset()`, of images, basically, acquired this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_directory,
    image_size = (image_height, image_width),
    batch_size = batch_size
)
```

So, this dataset has `(data, label)` where the data is a tensor of shape `(batch_size, image_height, image_width, channels)` [I don't really need the labels it assigns]. So far so good. The problem is, I need to process this dataset, applying certain operations to the images, and, this dataset is too big to load everything in memory (that's why `batch_size` is there). According to the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map), `tf.data.Dataset.map()` is the function I need (or so I assume....).

```
def image_processing(data):
    print(data.shape)
    
    # Do some operations.
    # Do some copies [because np.arrays help me more...].
    copy = np.array(data, copy=True)

    # Change some pixels, like, zero out a square in this image
    # It sad that TensorFlow can't do this assignment if it were a tf.Tensor:
    copy[10:80,10:80] = np.array([0,0,0])

    # Do more things, and when done return.
    return something


processed_dataset = dataset.map(lambda image, label: (image_processing(image), label))
```

First of all, the shape returned by the print: `(None, 200, 200, 3)` instead of `(32, 200, 200, 3)`, or, instead of `(200, 200, 3)` [which is what I'd expect from reading the documentation] [let's assume batch of 32, and images 200x200], and this is messing my code, because, I need to do assigments, like, take the ith image, and change a couple pixels: `data[i][12:15,40:50] = np.array([1,2,3])` and things like that.

Basically, that's the error message: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'`.

---

**In summary, my question:** How can I get a `processed_dataset`, where the processing steps will not be whole tensor operations, but instead, will be changing individual values in the data (say, individual pixels), for certain images (say, the ith image, jth image, etc)?

---

If you must know, I am running this in Ubuntu. Tensorflow version is:

```
>>> tf.__version__
'2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over small portions of the dataset with the `tf.data.Dataset.take()` method.

```
sub_dataset = dataset.take(10)
for element in sub_dataset:
    # work with the image
```

Here is the [documentation].(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take)